# IE 11 css SVG fill alternative?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm currently working on a site which determines the colour of an svg icon by the css element fill, I've had a look on caniuse and I've noticed that it cannot be done on IE, is there a fallback css element I can use instead of this? Or will I have to go through and manually change the colour of the svg's myself for this browser.

Cheers!

Comment: Using the fill attribute `fill="color"`

Comment: Could you post a link to this caniuse page ? Are you sure you were looking at the CSS `fill` property and not e.g at the non standards `text-stroke` and `text-fill` ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to demonstrate the IE issue that you think you have.